# Setting Facebook Achievement from Flash

Tags: php, facebook, flash, facebook-php-sdk, achievements

I'm setting up achievements for a game I'm working on. Flash sends the command to unlock the achievement, as well as the url to the achievement. On my server, I have the code that passes the display order and achievement url from Flash to Facebook. When I press the button to unlock the achievement in Flash, it unlocks successfully in my game and I can see it on the ticker. When I click the button from within the iFrame to unlock the achievement it won't unlock. Logging $result will return 1, but it will not show up in the ticker or count as unlocked.

postachievement.php

```
<?php
    include 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '[APP_ID]',
    'secret' => '[APP_SECRET]', ));

     $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

     //$uid = $facebook->getUser();
     $uid = "[Static ID for Testing]";

     $achievement = $_POST['achievement'];

     $achievement_URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $uid . '/achievements';
     $achievement_result = https_post($achievement_URL,
         'achievement=' . $achievement
         . '&access_token=' . $access_token);
         error_log($result);

         function https_post($uri, $postdata) 
     {
        $ch = curl_init($uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
     }
```

Achievements.as

```
package Facebook
{
public class Achievements
{
    public static var trophy:Achievements;
    private static var achievement:String;              // URL of the Achievement

    public function Achievements()
    {
        trophy = this;
    }

    public static function testAchievement1():void
    {
        achievement     = "https://(URL)/zombies/game/achievements/test6.html";
        Database.data.giveAchievement(achievement);
    }

    public static function testAchievement2():void
    {
        achievement     = "https://(URL)/zombies/game/achievements/test7.html";
        Database.data.giveAchievement(achievement);
    }

    public static function testAchievement3():void
    {
        achievement     = "https://(URL)/zombies/game/achievements/test8.html";
        Database.data.giveAchievement(achievement);
    }   

    public static function testAchievement4():void
    {
        achievement     = "https://(URL)/zombies/game/achievements/test9.html";
        Database.data.giveAchievement(achievement);
    }   

    public static function testAchievement5():void
    {
        achievement     = "https://(URL)/zombies/game/achievements/test10.html";
        Database.data.giveAchievement(achievement);
    }   
}
}
```

Some snippets from the Database class that deal with the achievements.

Database.as

```
// Give Achievement
private static var achieveLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
private static var achieveRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest;
achieveRequest.url  = "https://(URL)/zombies/game/postachievement.php";

    // Grant Player an Achievement
public function giveAchievement(_achievement:String):void
{
    var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    vars.achievement        = _achievement;

    achieveRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    achieveRequest.data = vars;
    achieveLoader = new URLLoader();
    achieveLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    achieveLoader.load(achieveRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is getting the Player's access token rather than the applications. I got the application's access token and statically put it into the variable. As long as the app's access token doesn't change, this will work.